# Can junk mail from the Royal Mail be classed as fly tipping?

Tags: united-kingdom, mail

Despite a no junk mail sign, unsurprisingly I still get it though the door. I decided to take a stand for the fun of it and called Dominoes Pizza head office to complain. I asked them to stop fly tipping inside my home but they said it was nothing to do with them, they paid Royal Mail to do it. This did seem to irritate me so I asked them would it be OK and nothing to do with me if I paid someone to fly tip trash in their restaurants. As expected, they hung up. I then contacted Royal Mail to complian that my local postman was ignoring the no junk mail sign. The person on the line told me that posting junk mail was part of the postmans job and it was OK to ignore the sign. This did not go down well either. I gave them my objections to this and I also asked about how I could get this to stop. I was quite surprised as to how this works.

Firstly you are considered automatically opted in unless you opt out.

There is no easy way of opting out. You have to download a form from [here](https://personal.help.royalmail.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/293/%7E/how-do-i-opt-out-of-receiving-any-leaflets-or-unaddressed-promotional-material%3F). Print it out and send it off.

The opt out only lasts for 2 years. After that you have to reapply.

Anyway my questions are these... How is this even legal? Can I invoice the advertiser or Royal Mail for a disposal fee? Can I get the Royal Mail prosecuted for fly tipping? From a health and safety point of view they are causing a fire risk not to mention damage to the environment. I want it to stop but object to this implied opt in and having to send a form when conveniently for them, it cannot be done online or even over the phone. Rather than be a victim, I wish to profit from this or at the very least annoy them back.  I welcome your thoughts. :-)

It is not just me, there are millions of UK residents affected. Can it be stopped?

Edit: Just to clarify, these are flyers/leaflets. Not unaddressed mail in envelopes.

Comment: Is this actual post with a [pre-printed] stamp, or just a leaflet delivered by a convenient door-to-door method?

Comment: It will be the latter. Royal Mail have to deliver addressed letters. RM does not know what is in an addressed letter.

Comment: It would be quicker and easier just to complete the form every 2 years than to get hot under the collar and make predictably pointless phone calls.

Answer (score 3):

### Junk mail is perfectly legal

From [Preventing unsolicited mail](https://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN05762/SN05762.pdf) published by the House of Commons Library:

> It is not illegal for a company to send unsolicited mail unless the material is obscene or threatening. No legislation exists which can protect a householder from receiving it.
>
> If postage has been paid, Royal Mail is legally obliged to deliver all addressed mail, which includes mail that is addressed “to the occupier” as well as mail that is personally addressed. However, there are various options available to an individual who wishes to stop unwanted and unsolicited direct marketing mail.

From you description, it appears that Dominos paid for the mail to be delivered “to the occupier” and the Royal Mail has a legal obligation to do so (unless you opt out).

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is more of a privacy violation and the commercial use of "stolen" data.

Since this is not consented/approved/agreed mail, inquire as to where they obtained your name and address and take it from there.

Many more, I believe, will join your cause.

Comment: You do not need to know a persons name or address to hand deliver a flyer. There is no data collected until you opt out.

Comment: Names and addresses can be obtained from the [electoral roll](https://www.gov.uk/electoral-register/view-electoral-register). Unless a voter has opted to be excluded from the commercial version, the details are not 'stolen'. Even when opted out, the electoral roll is still a public document, but not usable for automated mailing.